# why are there so many include directories?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

On my Ubuntu environment (20.04, arm64), I found out that there is more than just one single include directory.
When I executed the following commands, I've got 4 include directories that gcc is aware of.

- command

  ```
  LC_ALL=C gcc -v -xc -E /dev/null 2>&1 | sed -ne '/search starts here/,/End of search list/p'
  ```
- result

  ```
  #include "..." search starts here:
  #include <...> search starts here:
    /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/include
    /usr/local/include
    /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
    /usr/include
  End of search list.
  ```

I couldn't tell what the differences are between them.
Could you explain them please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `/usr/include` is your standard location for system headers installed from package manager.
- `/usr/local/include` is a location for system headers installed from packages that you've installed yourself. Due to ordering anything installed here would override those inside `/usr/include`, but it is guaranteed that no system package would clash with these (as system packages would not modify `/usr/local`).
- `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu` would contain ARM64-specific headers; this is handy because your system might have a cross-compiler installed that would have headers for some architecture besides this one.
- `/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/include` are the headers specifically for your GCC version 9 of compiler on ARM64, these will contain the necessary **freestanding headers** for your compiler and support for the compiler intrinsics. You can have several compilers installed in my machine - I've got GCC 9, 11 and 12 myself, side by side.

  The freestanding headers as specified by the C11 are `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`.

Notice that the paths in these lists are present *only* if the corresponding directories exist. For example I do not have `/usr/local/include` directory myself, so it is pruned from my list. There is a list of such in the full output prefixed with `ignoring nonexistent directory`.

Comment: As for the freestanding headers in `.../aarch64-linux-gnu/...`, it helps with the understanding that these headers are "freestanding" because they are "header only", i.e. nothing in them refers to any library function. They contain definitions and typedefs which actually the *compiler* knows best how to do. Hence, they are part of the *compiler* distribution, not the *library* distribution.